# Sum of all durations in a datatable in c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a issue in calculating the sum total amount of hours from a datatable. I would like it to calculate and display as HHHHH:MM:SS to a textbox ? Is it i need to changed the query string to be another data type? It is stored a milliseconds in the database.

MYSQL query to populate the datatable

```
SELECT Switch_Name, Extn, COUNT(*) as Total_Calls, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(cldp_talk_time/1000)) as Talk_Time, SUM(cost/100000) as 'Total_Cost
```

This is what is in the datatable.

```
Talk_Time
16:46:11
03:56:20
03:26:55
00:50:09
00:46:48
00:17:18
00:09:55
00:00:19
```

I am currently then using the command below to calculate the sum of time the issue is that it is displaying as DD HH:MM:SS and it then hits a limit of 99 23:59:59 and then crashes out. I have tried converting to datetime but makes no differnce.

```
  minsclltxt.Text = callrecdt.Compute("Sum(Talk_Time)", "").ToString();
```

minsclltxt currently shows as

```
"6.13:25:33"
```

would like to see

```
"157:25:33"
```

Hopefully this is clear

Comment: Your last snippet regarding formatting a time span for display seems like a different question than the rest of your post.

Comment: No sorry this is the same question just trying to explain what I am currently doing and the result I would like to see

Comment: Is your problem that you can't sum past 100 days or that you can't display a time span how you want? Those are two different questions.

Comment: I have never wanted it to display as DD HH:MM:SS but have lived with it until I hit over 99 days today and now would like it to display as HHHH:MM:SS I will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to TimeSpan, calculate sum of Ticks, then create a new TimeSpan from that result.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than directly invoking `ToString` on the result of your `Calculate` call you need to keep the resultant `TimeSpan` instance long enough to give your own string format. None of the standard string formats include "total hours", but `TimeSpan` defines it as a property. Here's a simple console app demonstrating:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Talk_Time", typeof(TimeSpan));

    for (var i = 0; i < 101; i++)
    {
        var dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Talk_Time"] = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    var sum = (TimeSpan)dt.Compute("Sum(Talk_Time)", "");
    Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}:{2}", sum.TotalHours, sum.Minutes, sum.Seconds);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

This prints `2424:0:0` to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't get it to HHHH:MM:SS but this will do.

Thanks

```
                var sum = (TimeSpan)callrecdt.Compute("Sum(Talk_Time)", "");
                minsclltxt.Text = String.Format("{0} Days {1} Hours {2} Minutes {3} Seconds", sum.Days,sum.Hours,sum.Minutes,sum.Seconds);
```